# Robohydra startup issue

Tags: webserver

Getting error when running Robohydra. This a [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c0axz08rlyqm0dc/Screenshot%202015-01-12%2011.35.00.png?dl=0)

Tried to reinstall robohydra few times, no luck.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Problem was fixed by developer in the last commit.